# Node.js + Express + Redis, when to close connection?

Tags: node.js, express, node-redis

I have a Node application that uses [Express](http://expressjs.com/) and [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis). I'm following the approach outlined in the [Learning Node](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024606.do) book and creating a single client for the life of the application. Given this approach, when do I call `close()` on the redis client? Do I even need to?

Relevant code

```
var express = require( 'express' ),
    redis = require( 'redis' );

var app = express(),
    config = require( './config/application' )[ app.get( 'env' ) ];

// create Redis client
var redisClient = redis.createClient();
redisClient.on( 'error', function( err ) {
  console.log( 'Error' + err );
} );
// select the database
redisClient.select( config.redis_database );

...
/* more setup, route defintions, etc. */
...

http.createServer( app ).listen( 4000, function() {
  console.log( 'Server started and ready for action!' );
});
```

Answer (score 19):

You have a couple options.

1. Be lazy and set an idle timeout for all clients on the redis server. Then when a client is idle for too long the server would just kill their connection.
2. Kill the connection when the node process exits.

.

```
process.on("exit", function(){
    redisClient.quit();
});
```

Comment: You can only perform synchronous operations inside "exit" event handler. The process will die before any "quit" command is send to the redis server.

Comment: close() function doesn't exists. Use redisClient.quit();

Comment: If you are killing the node process anyway, why do you need to explicitly "quit" the redis client?  When the node process dies, any connection resources associated with it will be released/disconnected anyway.

Comment: @Phil, u wanna say if I disconnect from my data source, there are no reasons to disconnect redis?

Answer (score 7):

: The question was 3 years ago and you might get answer already, anyway this might be useful for some new people.

You can make nodejs process listens to `SIGINT` which is interrupt sent from keyboard via the following code

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    redisClient.quit();
    console.log('redis client quit');
});
```

Then you can either `Ctrl+C` from the keyboard, or send such signal via `kill -SIGINT <process id>`. When that happens, that code will be executed.

This is when we don't know exactly when to quit redis client, or we want external control to cleanly quit/clear resource we was using.

Comment: In addition to SIGINT, it might also help to also listen to SIGTERM to handle the `kill <process id>` command

Comment: @ifelsemonkey that makes sense too.

Comment: Ultimately, is there no reason to quit executing each request? I mean, for example, we have a lot of different requests. In some of these requests, we need to get some redis data. Are there no reasons for each request to make a connection and at the end of this request to make a disconnection?

Comment: @daparic Additional note: `SIGTERM` is **NOT SUPPORTED** on Windows. But it can be just listened to. The `SIGILL` and `SIGTERM` signals are not generated under Windows. They are included for ANSI compatibility. See [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/xdkz3x12(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#signal-events)