# Close redis connection on google cloud function end

Tags: node.js, redis, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-memorystore

How do you close the connection to a redis memory store from a cloud function when the cloud function instance terminates? (I believe to close I need to call redis.quit(), but I just don't know when, and I cannot close them immediately after a function returns because the function instance can be [reused](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/amirku/make_cloud_functions_run_only_once/))

Because I'm just leaving the connections open, right now I am getting "ECONNRESET" errors.

Alternatively if something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22467916/3381291) is not possible:

```
process.on("exit", function(){//also process is not defined in cloud functions
    redisClient.quit();
});
```

Is the best option to specify a timeout in the redis config? (How do you do this in gcp memorystore?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your Cloud Function entry function returns, your container is eligible to be terminated without notice.

You have two choices:

- Open and close connections at every function invocation
- Use connection pooling and manage connection errors which goes against the intended usage of the Cloud Functions.

If your functions are keeping the container warm, connection pooling with error handling "might" have benefit at a not-insignificant cost of error handling and testing all possible problems. Cloud Functions apps should be designed to be "stateless". Trying to persist state (connections, data, etc) between invocations in Cloud Functions is not a good strategy.

I would design my system using option #1. Cloud Functions are "lightweight" meaning startup, do the task quickly and shutdown.

Comment: The docs explicitly promote using connections across invocations as a performance optimisation: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/networking

I think asking if there is some lifecycle hook or signal to determine that the function instance is being terminated to do clean-up, such as closing connections, is valid. I have the same question...

Comment: @WilhelmUschtrin - this is a three year old answer. I recommend that you create a new question. Yes, Google docs recommend initializing items that take a long time in global space. However, as with most tasks, you must know what you are doing. Connection management is one of those items. The question is **How do you close the connection to a redis memory store from a cloud function when the cloud function instance terminates?**. Your comment's link does not solve that problem. Since you do not know that a container is being terminated, choice one is the recommended solution.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't. And I was hoping to find something somewhere in the docs, but didn't. And while choice one is technically correct, the overhead of opening and closing connections on each invocation seems like an unacceptable overhead. As this really seems like a shortcoming of Cloud Functions, maybe the solution then is to just use Cloud Run?

Comment: @WilhelmUschtrin - The key is to understand how TCP works. If a service (Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, etc) is not providing CPU time to a connection, the connection will error out. Cloud Run supports always on CPU at a higher cost. Connections have a time cost but serverless also has tradeoffs. Use the right service for the job instead of trying to fit the job to the service.

Comment: I was also wondering about this. This example in the gcloud redis docs just keeps things open https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-functions#configuring

I'm currently using the new "using" keyword in Javascript to close the connect automatically once the client goes out of scope, but I do wonder about the overhead of opening/closing a connection every invocation (I will try to measure it)

Comment: @ThijsKoerselman - Opening connections is an expensive operation. The key is to open a connection, use it until unnecessary, and close it. TLS connections require validating certificates, negotiating encryption, etc. IMHO serverless is overused by many. Often a simple compute engine instance will provide better services at a lower design cost.

Comment: Yes, sometimes it also makes me wonder... I think 2nd gen functions might improve things a little, as they are based on cloud-run and one instance can handle multiple connections and run for longer. I use them now with min-instances > 0, so I think keeping the connection open in global scope will be a good solution. But not really serverless anymore if you keep instances running :)

Comment: That is still serverless - you are not deploying or managing servers, but I do get your point.